# Nightwatch count number of element

Tags: javascript, count, nightwatch

I'am a newbie with Nightwatch and i would like to count the number of element. I am able to do this but I don't understand how the variable is interpreted, here my code :

```
browser.elements('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]', function (elements) {
                var nb = 0    
                elements.value.forEach(function (elementsObj, index) {   
                    browser.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function (result) {
                        if (result.value != "") {
                            nb = nb + 1
                            console.log(result.value)
                        }
                        //console.log("There are :  "  + nb)
                    })
                    //console.log("There are :  "  + nb)
                })
```

This display all elements I want. The output is :
Element 1
Element 2
and so on...

Now, I would like to have this :

There are X elements :
Element 1
Element 2
And so on...

But I try to print my variable "nb" but it doesn't work... How can I store and display my "nb" variable ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that those commented console.log when not commented are executed before your loop ends... and therefore they are most likely returning :
"There are  : 0"

Have you tried to "await" for the forEach loop to end?

Maybe something like:

```
browser.elements('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]', function (elements) {
                var nb = 0    
                elements.value.forEach(async function (elementsObj, index) {   
                   await browser.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function (result) {
                        if (result.value != "") {
                            nb = nb + 1
                            console.log(result.value)
                        }
                        //console.log("There are :  "  + nb)
                    })
                    console.log("There are :  "  + nb)
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the values in an array. And then parse the length after the forEach loop is completed. something like this:

```
browser.elements('xpath', '/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]', function (elements) {
     var nb = []
     elements.value.forEach(function (elementsObj, index) {
       browser.elementIdText(elementsObj.ELEMENT, function (result) {
         if (result.value != "") {
           console.log(result.value)
           nb.push(result.value)
         }
       })
     })
     console.log('There are ' + nb.length() + 'elements')
     for (const nbItem of nb) {
       console.log(nbItem)
     }
   })
```